# Multi page Vue app combined with Flask and Nginx - can't run in sub path

Tags: vue.js, nginx-config

I'm running a multi page Vue app, linked with Flask, running on a server with Nginx. I can get this working fine. However, I am going to be running multiple Vue apps on the same server.

I've updated the **router.js** file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: '/app1/',
});
```

And also the **vue.config.js** file:

```
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
      electronBuilder: {
          builderOptions: {
              publicPath: '/app1/',
          },
      },
  },
};
```

And this is a snippet of my **nginx config** file that is copied here: */etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default*

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name website.com;
        error_page  405     =200 $uri;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;


        location /app1/ {
                root /Website/frontend/dist;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
         }

        location /status {
               include proxy_params;
               proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1:8000;
       }
```

As you can see, I'm trying to just get the first app running - but I'm having issues.

In the current nginx config - I can *access website.com/status* fine, but I'm getting a 403 forbidden error when I try and access *website.com/app1* or *website.com/app1/*

If I change in my nginx config file, from

```
location /app1/ 
to
location /
```

Then the site works fine.

However, that's problematic as when I want to introduce app2, I will need to point to another *dist* directory.

The error in the Nginx error logs when I don't have a *"/"* path, shows that Nginx is trying to look under the folder *"/usr/share/nginx/html/"*. Obviously, I can copy all my files from app1 there and the site works. But again, thats not going to work when I need to expand to additional apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested, the issue was the `vue.config.js` file and that Nginx couldn't find the files in the dist folder linked to app1. Adding this information got it working.

```
module.exports = {
        publicPath: './',
        assetsDir: './',
        outputDir: './dist/app1/',
};
```